# Represent array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array or a list from linq. I want to show it as a string in console! What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most generic answer that I can give to you is to loop through each element and use the `ToString()` method on each element.

Alternatively, you can serialize the Array/List to Xml.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to use Json serializer, its visually simple

Answer (score 7):

```
String.Join(delimiter, array);
```

You could represent it as:

```
Console.WriteLine("{" + String.Join(", ", array) + "}");
```

Of course, I think this only works with strings.

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over it?

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can loop through it if it's a collection or an array. Check [the `foreach` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx)

```
List<Object> list = ...

foreach (Object o in list) {
  Console.WriteLine(o.ToString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like a more LINQ approach you could use the following:

```
String text = String.Join("," + Environment.NewLine, list.Select(item => item.ToString()).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

The first parameter of the Join specifies which characters should be inserted between items in the array. Using the .Select on the list is for getting a string representation of your item in the array.

Answer (score -1):

I would want some more information about exactly what you want to see, but at first blush I'd try something like:

```
public string StringFromArray(string[] myArray)
    {
        string arrayString = "";
        foreach (string s in myArray)
        {
            arrayString += s + ", ";
        }
        return arrayString;
    }
```

Comment: You've just reinvented String.Join

Comment: @Bart, Not quite: this version will add a pointless extra ", " at the end of the joined string. It'll also be slower and eat more memory than string.Join ;)